# Converting html headings with php regex

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have got string with html tagged text:

```html
<p>Some random text</p>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

I want to convert it into something like that:

```html
<p>Some random text</p>
<h2 id="This_is_a_heading">This is a heading</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

This simple code almost does it:

```php
 $patterns = array('#(<h2>)(.*)(</h2>)#i');
 $replace = array('<h2 id="\2">\2</h2>');
 $text = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $text);
```

But I still don't know how to replace `whitespaces` with `underscores` in `id` attribute, I end up with this in `$text`:

```html
<p>Some random text</p>
<h2 id="This is a heading">This is a heading</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

I've tried to search for a few hours now but no luck. Please help.

Comment: You would be better off with an html parser. On a side note, if you want to run another replace on the replace, you need preg_replace_callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using an HTML Parser**

This is the recommended way to go about parsing HTML. Unless you are absolutely sure the format of the HTML string is totally fixed, regex processing is insufficient and you must use an HTML parser. Here's a solution using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class that ships with PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($text);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $tag) {
    $nodeValue = (string) $tag->nodeValue;
    $id = str_replace(' ', '_', $nodeValue);
    $tag->setAttribute('id', $id);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Using regular expressions**

For a simple replace, a DOM parser might be overkill. If you don't care about the accuracy of the results that much, then you *can* use a regex to accomplish the task. Note that this might break if the markup contains additional attributes or extra tags in between.

In this case, your `preg_replace()` won't work as it can't modify the backreferences. Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#(<h2>)(.*)(</h2>)#i', function ($m) {
    $id = str_replace(' ', '_',$m[2]);
    return "<h2 id=\"$id\"></h2>";
}, $text);
```

Comment: @mocniak: Happy to have helped! (I've updated the answer to include bit more explanation - I hope you find it useful :)